# CSS for mobile header

Tags: css, nav

I am trying to fix my mobile nav bar so it will be fixed and background will show all the time, (it's currently taking styling from the main nav for desktop which is transparent)

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {#navbar {position:fixed; background-color: #383736;}
```

This code is currently not working, can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: https://dev5.runforthehills.com/ sorry here is the URL incase you need it

Comment: Please create a [MRE] within your question.

Comment: And FYI, there is no element on your page with an id of "navbar".

Comment: Hi Turnip, thanks for replying. I've tried to include the code that i think is correct, I don't know how to explain better, is there any other information that I need to include?

Comment: Yes, you need to include the relevant HTML and CSS as a working example of the problem _within your question_. That would include the CSS that your media query overrides.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the property :

```css
top: 0;
```

In your css

Answer (score 0):

A html element with id navbar doesn´t exist in your code

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .main-header__inner {
        position:fixed; 
        background-color: #383736;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved on the page you linked with:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  header{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```